# Google sheets insert a row into a mapped array

Tags: arrays, dictionary, google-sheets, insert

I have a google sheets with a routine to update a master sheet with data from another sheet. The master sheet has a name in column 1 and data in the adjacent 18 columns.  The Master sheet is sorted by name.

Using google scripts, I map the master into an array and then read the weekly sheet row-by-row and update the master (if necessary).  When done the master sheet should be updated since it was mapped to my array which was updated.

On a weekly basis I want to update the master sheet with the weekly results.

Here is my question: I might encounter another name in the weekly sheet not found in the master.  In this case I need to create a new row in the master array (keeping alphabetical order)

I've looked into push but I don't know how to keep it in alphabetical order.  Alternatively I could add it to the end and then sort the array but I'm not sure how the mapping will work.

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
function updateRinger() {
  var WEEKLYPOINTER = 1;
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var best = ss.getSheetByName("Ringer");
  var name = ss.getSheetByName("Info");
  var sheetNameFromUser = name.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var latest = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameFromUser);
  var ringer = best.getRange(2,1,best.getLastRow(),best.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();
  var weekly = latest.getRange(1,1,latest.getLastRow(),latest.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //Load the best ringer scores into an array and update them if necessary
  var updates = ringer.map(updateScores);

    //Replace the best scores spreadsheet from the array
  ringer = best.getRange(2,1,best.getLastRow(),best.getLastColumn()-1).setValues(updates);

  function updateScores(player){
  //
  //Compare the weekly extract against the best scores for every member and every hole
  //
    //First - Loop through the weekly extract and compare names against the "best scores"
    for (i=WEEKLYPOINTER; i<weekly.length; i++){
      if (weekly[i][0] == player[0] ){  //Found a name match
        //Now compare all 18 holes for a new lower score
        for (j=1; j<19; j++){
          if((player[j] > weekly[i][j]) || (player[j] === "")){  // Found a new "lowest score"
            //Update the best score for that player
            Logger.log("Update Needed: " + player[0] + " Hole: "+ j + " Old Score: "+player[j] + " New Score: " + weekly[i][j]);
            player[j] = weekly[i][j];
          }
        }
        return player;  //Players stats were updated
      } 
    }
    return player;  //No Update this week
  }
```

Comment: Why not just have your master list a formula that gets all unique names and then sort alphabetically? Something like... `=Sort(Unique(filter(A:A,A:A<>"")))`

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.